# Accessing files and modules in different directories in Python

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7. I have the following directory structure:

```
alogos
- resources
  - __init__.py
  - test.py
- lib
- __init__.py
  - utils.py
- common
  - config
    - config.json
```

My utils.py is the following:

```
def read_json_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as data:
        json_data=json.load(data)
    return json_data
```

My `test.py` has the following:

```
from lib.utils import read_json_data

running_data = read_json_data('common/config/config.json')
print running_data
```

when I try to run `python test.py` from the `resources` directory, I get the following error:

`ImportError: No module named lib.utils`

What is the correct way to access files and modules

Comment: Have you tried running_data = read_json_data('../common/config/config.json')

Comment: Files in one directory in a module are never going to be able to access files in another sibling directory. You might want to consider moving `test` out of `alogos` altogether and placing `test.py` in the same folder as `alogos/`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: @tfv: Hardcoding like that isn't the right solution. What if OP wants to deploy to a Windows environment where file paths delimited by \ instead of / are the norm?

Comment: He already has a hardcoded path, I have just suggested to correct it ...

Answer (score 2):

Your `lib.utils` module is not present in the current directory (and apparently not anywhere else `import` checks), and so the `import` fails.

The [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) details the module search path:

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> ```
> * the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> * PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> * the installation-dependent default.
> ```
>
> After initialization, Python programs can modify sys.path. The
>   directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning
>   of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means
>   that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of
>   the same name in the library directory. This is an error unless the
>   replacement is intended. See section Standard Modules for more
>   information.

While this is certainly not the only way, what I would do would be to have your `lib.utils` module as a separate module, stored in a local *Pypi* server (*Artifactory* is one example, but there are others, such as *devpi*) where you can install it just like any other module, just from a different index URL from the regular Pypi. That way, any of your scripts can use it just like any other module, and it obviates the need to play assorted path-related games that can add unnecessary complexity.